# Integrating Drupal with OpenERP

Tags: drupal, odoo

We have a requirement that we need to integrate `OpenERP` with `Drupal`.

I investigated but could not find any Drupal addon/module which will do the desired job.

I also investigated and found that `OpenERP` is based on client server architecture, where Server exposes `XMl-RPC/SOAP` based webservices and client uses these services for all business operations and all user actions.

More information can be found [here.](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html)

As per from the document, all  the business processing is done on the server.

So considering this design in mind, and considering that we can create custom modules in drupal which can perform `xml-prc/soap` operations, it seems we can integrate `drupal` with `OpenERP`.

Is this the only way, or i am missing something.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: We are going with custom implementation. So i am marking this as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your information `OpenERP` doesn't support `SOAP` web services, so thats sure you need to develop `drupal` module using `XML-RPC` Web Services !

Here is an [example](https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/#php) provided by `openerp_doc` for `PHP` integration using `xml-rpc` web services

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience in integrating `OpenERP` with other applications but web services should be the way to go. May be you can benefit from studying how others did to link `OpenERP` with other solutions like `Magento`, `Prestashop`, `ezPublish`...

Lastly an other interesting solution appeared for `OpenERP EAI`, `Terminatooor`.

And by the way, seems like others are working on this too: http://openerp.netquatro.com/openerp_cms

Anyway, it would be great to have a `Drupal` integration module !

Hope it helps
Bests